# Regex between two characters and over multiple lines

Tags: regex

I have got this string here:

```
-Node: song
--Tag: ItsyWitsySpider
---lyrics: The itsy witty spider climbed up the waterspout.
       Down came the rain,
       and washed the spider out
--Tag: BaBaBlackSheep
---lyrics: Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool?
       Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!
       One for the master,
       And one for the dame,
--Tag:IfYoureHappyAndYouKnowIt
...
```

I want to get all of

```
       The itsy witty spider climbed up the waterspout.
       Down came the rain,
       and washed the spider out
```

Through the use of regex
So far  my best regex is :

```
(?<=ItsyWitsySpider\n)(?:_*lyrics: ).*?(?=_)
```

Trying on here : https://regex101.com/r/3myZwB/1
it doesn't seem to work 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the lookbehind and make sure to match the hypen after a newline:

```
(?<=ItsyWitsySpider\n---lyrics: ).*?(?=\r?\n-)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `ItsyWitsySpider\n---lyrics:`  Match ItsyWitsySpider, a newline and `---lyrics:`
- `)` Close positive lookbehind
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the left is

  - `\r?\n-` Match a newline, then match `-`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WPMnuJ/1)

---

Or you might use a capturing group instead of a lookbehind which will be a bit more efficient where you could match all the lines that don't start with `--Tag`.

```
ItsyWitsySpider\r?\n---lyrics: (.*(?:\r?\n(?!--Tag).*)*)\r?\n--Tag
```

In parts

- `ItsyWitsySpider\r?\n---lyrics:`  Match `ItsyWitsySpider` till `lyrics:`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\r?\n(?!--Tag)` Match a newline and assert that the next line does not start with `--Tag`
    - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `)*` Close group an repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `\r?\n--Tag` Match a newline followed by `--Tag`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M4iBip/1)

Comment: @makingAMess Please upvote the answer instead of leaving thank-you comments.

Comment: @jrook 
I don't have enough rep sadly
EDIT: looks like I do now :-D

Comment: @The fourth bird
also the explanations were nice

Comment: @makingAMess The best way to thank others for helping you is to [pay it forward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your text contains hyphens `-` but your regex looks for underscores `_`. Your regex is supposed to be

```
(?<=ItsyWitsySpider\n)(?:-*lyrics: ).*?(?=-)
```

though a much faster regex would be

```
(?<=ItsyWitsySpider\n)(?:_*lyrics: )[^-]*
```

Comment: Ended up using The fourth bird & a bit of yours in the end 

Answer (score 1):

```
/The itsy.*([\r\n].*)*out/gm
```

```js
let re = /The itsy.*([\r\n].*)*out/gm
let str = `
      -Node: song
      --Tag: ItsyWitsySpider
      ---lyrics: The itsy witty spider climbed up the waterspout.
             Down came the rain,
             and washed the spider out
      --Tag: BaBaBlackSheep
      ---lyrics: Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool?
             Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!
             One for the master,
             And one for the dame,
      --Tag:IfYoureHappyAndYouKnowIt
...
`

console.log(str.match(re))
```